# Text and Number Format on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I have question that when I want to compare between a1= 1.3 b1= 3 and a2= 1.3 b2= 2  on excel for example       `=IF(a1>a2,"Yes",IF(a1=a2,IF(b1>b2,"Yes","No"),"no"))`

First time it's okay, but then I changed value from b1 =1  it changed to "no"  then I changed it back to b1= 3  it's still "no"

I think it concern on format in the cell.

Another concern is if I use like 1.3.1 compare to 1.3.1.2    it doesn't have any problem, but when I use only 1.3 (one decimal point) it always have problem

It's hard to explain you should try to compare between x.x  and x.x.x also if you have a good another VBA code to compare version number

It like  1 decimal point excel see as number, but  many decimal point excel see as text

How do I fix this (I have try change to text format but it work 1 time after you change value in cell it's go back to error.)

Due to my English is poor.    to make it clearer    `"How do i make x.x see as text so that i can compare with x.x.x :) "`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the evaluation to see which part of the formula doesn't evaluate as you expect?

Comment: This question makes no sense. `x.x.x` can never possibly be a number, and therefore can't be compared as one. If you need to compare them, you need to do it as text; if you need an exact match, you'll need to use a substring of the longer one that is the same number of characters as the shorter one and compare those for equality.

Comment: yes x.x.x is see as text if you read carefully but x.x see as number

so is there anyway that to make excel see x.x  as text all the time

Comment: 1.3 will be treated as a number by Excel, but 1.3.1 will be treated like a string as it is not in any valid format for a number. So I am not surprised that you get different results.

Comment: -DeanOC 

yep but is there any way that i can turn x.x to text (string)

Comment: Enter x.x with an apostrophe ("'") at the beginning, as in '1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article/ post you may want to check. The first impression I had on your question is that you may be trying to do a version number comparison. Length and number of dot delimiters in your text could matter greatly.for now please check this,

http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-excel/1670840-compare-version-numbers-return-highest-value.html

Or else you may try the `log` as well:

=A1*10^(4-INT(LOG(A1)))

Or do a replace on trailing `.` dots and surely the second text becomes a decimal:

E.g. 1.3.4 will be 1.34 and 1.3.4.1.3 will be 1.3413

1.2.5.6 will be 125.6 and 1.2.4.6.1 will be 124.61

PS: not front of a machine. Will provide you with another code I have based on split by dot delimiter and compare.

Edit with a function: this will compare two version numbers with any number of dot points, treating it as a string/text. However in the case of 1.3.1 and 1.21.1 this takes 1.21.1 as the highest number.

```
Option Explicit

Function versionNumberComparison(ByRef rng1 As Range, ByRef rng2 As Range) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arrVersion1 As Variant, arrVersion2 As Variant
    Dim strVer1 As String, strVer2 As String
    Dim bool2 As Boolean, bool1 As Boolean
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not IsEmpty(rng1.Value) Then
        strVer1 = rng1.Value
        arrVersion1 = Split(rng1.Value, ".")
    Else
        versionNumberComparison = "Version number empty"
        GoTo Zoo
    End If
    If Not IsEmpty(rng2.Value) Then
        strVer2 = rng2.Value
        arrVersion2 = Split(rng2.Value, ".")
    Else
        versionNumberComparison = "Version number empty"
        GoTo Zoo
    End If

    If UBound(arrVersion1) > UBound(arrVersion2) Then
        x = UBound(arrVersion1)
        y = UBound(arrVersion2)
    ElseIf UBound(arrVersion1) < UBound(arrVersion2) Then
        x = UBound(arrVersion2)
        y = UBound(arrVersion1)
    Else
        x = UBound(arrVersion1)
        y = x
    End If

    i = 0
        While i <= y
            If IsNumeric(arrVersion1(i)) And IsNumeric(arrVersion2(i)) Then
                    If CInt(Trim(arrVersion1(i))) = CInt(Trim(arrVersion2(i))) Then
                        If i = y Then
                            If x <> y Then
                                If Len(strVer1) > Len(strVer2) Then
                                    bool1 = True
                                    bool2 = False
                                    GoTo PrintOut
                                Else
                                    bool2 = True
                                    bool1 = False
                                    GoTo PrintOut
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                            bool1 = False
                            bool2 = False
                    ElseIf CInt(Trim(arrVersion1(i))) > CInt(Trim(arrVersion2(i))) Then
                        bool1 = True
                        bool2 = False
                        GoTo PrintOut
                    Else
                        bool2 = True
                        bool1 = False
                        GoTo PrintOut
                    End If
            Else
                versionNumberComparison = "Enter Valid version numbers"
                GoTo Zoo
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Wend

PrintOut:

    If bool1 Then
        versionNumberComparison = strVer1
    ElseIf bool2 Then
        versionNumberComparison = strVer2
    Else
        versionNumberComparison = "Both the same"
    End If

Zoo:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @ethapicking check this out and let us know your thoughts : if you have any doubts.

Comment: i have try changing the . dot before it have a huge bug that 

excel if the number is 1.31.1 and 1.3.11    it cannot tell different between this

Comment: @eathapeking Which method are you referring to here in your comment? 1. VBA code 2. Log function? 3. Dot replace? BTW if are trying the `log` based formula then it has to be with the assumption/limitation that you will always consitent versioning... e.g. 1.31.1 and 1.3.11 then both are the same. Let me post you the code I have. Spare me sometime please as I am outside. :)

Comment: You dont have to be hurry... all answers that you had given me right now is very useful to me. i have to thank you a 1000 times

Comment: I think dot replace is not going to work. VBA is more prefer(i currently study about vba too)

Comment: @eathapeking check my edit please. The one higlighted in red is probably what you need to communicate to us clearly. Because for a number comparison, 21 is greater than 3. Please comment. :)

Comment: Yes it correct if i want to compare between 1.3 and 1.3.1  

or  7.1 with 7.1.3.2   

is it going to work

Comment: above is my previous trying you can see that some time it have to compare between x.x and x.x.x :3

Comment: YES it work Goshhh i have trying to find the way to make this work for weeks 

thank you so much

if i have anything thing i would like to ask can i ask by your email or PM

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22808/discussion-between-boncodigo-and-eathapeking)

Comment: I am glad it helped. There is an issue with the chat functions, well you can simply post a question, someone here will assist you for sure (given it's a proper question) :D