# Adding serial number irrespective of row deletion or insertion

Tags: vba, excel

I request your help in sorting out my issues on a small change in the below code.
I have code to insert rows while inserting row i would also like to add serial numbers just like 1,1.1,1.2 and 1.3....

The code below is already mentioned in the tool for adding serial numbers, can somebody tell me how the code can be tweaked to achieve the serial number in 1,1.1,1.2 format and if the rows are deleted or inserted it should add the serial number by 0.1 value based on previous serial number

```
dim m as integer
m = 0
Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Columns(columnidCol))
.Cells(r, columnidCol).Value = m + 1
```

The above code will give the value as 1, when I insert the row, the "columnidcol" is derived from the publicly declared constants as given below

```
Public Const numberoneCol As Integer = 2
Public Const columnidCol As Integer = numberoneCol
```

Please help me in modifying the above code.

Comment: I'd use formulas for that, not VBA code. `ROW` function is what you need.

Comment: @lifeinvba not sure if you are trying to do a versioning here.. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/14350999/1389394 why don't you show us the entire funciton code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store Serial Number in `ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties`:

```
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="SerialNumber", Type:=msoPropertyTypeString
....
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("SerialNumber").Value = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("SerialNumber").Value + 1
....
dim m as integer
m = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("SerialNumber").Value
.Cells(r, columnidCol).Value = m + 1
```

Comment: Hi Andrey thanks for your VBA code, as Iam new to VBA i would like to know where the below code to added in module is it top of the code where we define option explicit ? -- ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="SerialNumber", Type:=msoPropertyTypeString
....
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("SerialNumber").Value = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("SerialNumber").Value + 1
....

Comment: First of all you should add Custom Property by using first row of my code. Just insert it in empty sub and run. Then use this property as a storage for Serial Number (update it's value every time you insert/remove row)

Comment: Hi Andrey, the erro pops up after adding the code under sub is run time error 450 : Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: Try `msoPropertyTypeNumber` instead of `msoPropertyTypeString`: `ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="SerialNumber", Type:=msoPropertyTypeNumber, Value:=1`